# Template rendering error with expressjs and nunjucks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser, nunjucks

Essentially I'm trying to retrieve a flashed message from the node server and I'm getting a error which I am trying to rectify so that I can progress further with my web application.

I've tried modifying the code and I even fixed any issues with my nunjucks formatting with help from the nunjucks docs. Upon checking, it seems as if I can't run 'typeof' from within a nunjucks if expression.

```html
                {% if (typeof messages.error != "undefined") %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    <strong>Oops!</strong> {{ messages.error }}
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <script>console.log("first");</script>
                {% endif %}
```

```js
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const url = req.body.url;

    if (!url.startsWith('https://') && !url.startsWith('http://')) {
        req.flash('error', 'That doesn\'t appear to be a valid URL to me.');
    }
    return;
});
```

I'm trying to get the alert to not appear instead of the whole application crashing with a error.

````
Template render error: (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\views\index.html) [Line 33, Column 23]
  parseAggregate: expected comma after expression
    at Object._prettifyError (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:36:11)
    at Template.render (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:542:21)
    at e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:366:27
    at createTemplate (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:315:9)
    at handle (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:327:11)
    at e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:339:9
    at next (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:280:7)
    at Object.asyncIter (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:286:3)
    at Environment.getTemplate (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:321:9)
    at Environment.render (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:360:10)
    at NunjucksView.render (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\nunjucks\src\express-app.js:22:9)
    at tryRender (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\index.js:26:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (e:\Programming\nodejs\invisi.link\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)```
````

Comment: Use `messages and messages.error` instead of `(typeof messages.error != "undefined")` :) Also you can define a global function or filter to do exactly comparation.

Comment: Hi there Aikon! :) I did that, however, my message isn't flashing.

Comment: Try to replace `(typeof messages.error != "undefined")` by `true`. If the same error appears then you should check an another place.

Comment: Hey, I tried that and it doesn't work sadly. I'm not sure what you mean by 'you should check another place', could you please clarify?

Comment: I see a one suspect place in nunjuck template `(typeof messages.error != "undefined")`. So, if error raises again then I think that there is the error in another templated code.

Comment: I think I've just decided to ditch using Nunjucks and I'm going to rewrite in React. Thanks though! :)